# How to use each2 jquery plugin on dynamically generated content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to use each2 on html that is appended to the DOM, as a result of an AJAX call? The plugin itself is included at the top of the page, on page load.

I have some code like this:

```
$(".className").each2(function(){}));
```

where the .className divs are appended to the page via AJAX call. And I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: $(".className")(...).each2 is not a function

Edit:
link to each2 plugin
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cowboy/jquery-misc/master/jquery.ba-each2.js

This is how I am using it. It all works fine, except on dynamically added content. I'm aware that each2 can be replaced by other types of loops, is there a way to fix it without doing so?

```
   jQuery("some selector here").each2(function (i, element) {

   });
```

Comment: Please include some more code, also include the link to the each2 plugin, a demo in jsfiddle would be very helpful.

Comment: please provide us with more info on your question.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for that error is that each2 hasn't been loaded correctly.

Comment: No, each2 is loaded correctly, and it works on the html that was loaded on page load. It doesn't work on the dynamic HTML appended via AJAX. I suppose simply loading the each2 plugin again after AJAX call will fix it, but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If you change it to use each instead of each2 does it work?